# Xcode: Missing navigation bar

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, xcode6, storyboard

One of my views does not display a navigation bar when it runs. From what I can see the attributes are exactly (unless I missed something) the same as other views that work properly.

None of the attributes on the view controller are set. Top Bar is Translucent nav bar.

I also checked the attributes on the Navigation Controller and they were the same, but in case I missed something I created a new one ... no difference. Bar visibility is checked along with Extend edges (top and bottom.)

I've cleaned  and restarted Xcode

I haven't (intentionally) changed anything in the custom class for the view controller.

Obviously, I am missing something but what?

Comment: Have you tried using "View Debugging" to see what the view hierarchy looks like at the time the problem occurs?

Comment: Thanks -- that helped me -- there was a strange variable there pointing to a non-existent (so I thought) Navigation Controller. If that had been used it would not have taken me to the correct View controller but it had. Very strange. I reset the Simulator (I thought I had done that but maybe not. I really need to do that before anything but I did not think it would be related to Simulator settings.)